# How can I catch and handle a ajax signal in webkitgtk+

Tags: ajax, webkit, gtk

How can I catch and handle a ajax signal in webkitgtk+ ?

Comment: I tried, but failed. Only catch the ordinary HTTP requests

Comment: Well, your question is missing most of the things that would show the effort you have put in...